# Some questions about SQL group by week

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have some problems when coding SQL group by week.

I have a MySQL table named order.

In this entity, there are several attributes, called 'order_id', 'order_date', 'amount', etc.

I want to make a table to show the statistics of past 7 days order sales amount.

I think first I should get the today value.

Since I use Java Server Page, the code like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
int Month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String today = year + "-" + Month + "-" + day;
```

then, I need to use group by statement to calculate the SUM of past 7 day total sales amount.

like this:

```
    ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select order_date, SUM(amount) " + 
    "from `testing`.`order` GROUP BY order_date");
```

I have problem here. In my SQL, all order_date will be displayed.

How can I modify this SQL so that only display past seven days order sale amount?

Besides that, I discover a problem in my original SQL.

That is, if there is no sales on that day, no results would be displayed.

OF course, I know the ResultSet does not allow return null values in my SQL.

I just want to know if I need the past 7 order sales even the amount is 0 dollars,

Can I have other methods to show the 0?

Please kindly give me advices if you have idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it occurs to create with a script or with a stored procedure a calendar table with all dates.

However if you prefer you can create a table with few dates (in your case dates of last week) with a single query.

This is an example:

```
create table orders(
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
dorder date,
amount int
) engine = myisam;

insert into orders (dorder,amount)
values (curdate(),100),
       (curdate(),200),
       ('2011-02-24',50),
       ('2011-02-24',150),
       ('2011-02-22',10),
       ('2011-02-22',20),
       ('2011-02-22',30),
       ('2011-02-22',5),
       ('2011-02-19',10);

select t.cdate,sum(coalesce(o.amount,0)) as total 
from (
select curdate() - 
interval tmp.digit * 1 day as `cdate`
from (
select 0 as digit union all 
select 1 union all 
select 2 union all 
select 3 union all 
select 4 union all 
select 5 union all 
select 6 union all
select 7 ) as tmp) as t
left join orders as o
on t.cdate = o.dorder and o.dorder >= curdate() - interval 7 day
group by t.cdate
order by t.cdate desc
```

Hope that it helps. Regards.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. Results are doubled due to join. I've to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: I've modified the query. Now it works. However if someone can solve the problem without "/2 bad trick" I'd like to know it.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `/2` at all? I ran your code on SQL Server and got the expected results without it. `2011-02-27 300`, `2011-02-26 0` ... `2011-02-24 200` ... `2011-02-22 65` ....

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I'm drunk. You're right Martin. Results are rights. Time to go to sleep. :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "How can I modify this SQL so that only display past seven days order sale amount?"

Modify the SQL statement by adding a where clause to it:

Where order_date >= @date_7days_ago

The value for this @date_7days_ago date variable can be set before your statement:

Select @date_7days_ago = dateadd(dd,-7,getdate())

Adding that where clause to your query will return only those records which order date is in the last seven days.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since I usually do that inside a sql store procedure I forgot to mention that it is recommended you use a store procedure instead of a text statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(
  "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) 
  FROM table `testing`.`order`
  WHERE order_date >= DATE_SUB('" + today + "', INTERVAL 7 DAY)"
);
```

This will get you the number of orders made in the last 7 days, and 0 if there were none.